How to toggle theme color in c# aspnet core with toggle button inside partalview?
Explaination
I want to toggle the bootstrap 5.3 theme color through a button inside a partalview.
The toggle button is customised on my specific needs and the value is saved inside a cookie, which i call when needed.
The partial view will be included in the navbar menu.
For some strange reason i can not manage to find a suitable solution, for this case.
Question
How can this be implemented, which is the correct way?
The partialview code
@{

static void ToggleTheme()
{
    string bg = HttpContext.Request?.Cookies["mybg"]?.ToString();

    if (bg == "light" || bg == null)
    {
        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete("mybg");
        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("mybg", "dark");
    }
    else
    {
        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete("mybg");
        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("mybg", "light");
    }
}

}
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light" onclick="ToggleTheme()">

Theme


Why not do it using Javascript or Jquery if you are using it?

@RahulSharma I need it saved in a cookie because this way i can save this settings for a longer time. If you can point to me some implementation by using jquery, i would really appreciate it.

A simple demo you could follow:
Partial View(locates in Pages/Shared or Views/Shared folder)
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
@{
    // Read the current theme preference from the cookie
    string currentTheme = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request?.Cookies["mybg"]?.ToString();
}
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light" onclick="ToggleTheme()">ChangeTheme</button>
<script>
    // Function to toggle the theme and save preference in a cookie
    function ToggleTheme() {
        var currentTheme = document.body.classList.contains('theme-dark') ? 'light' : 'dark';

        // Toggle theme class on the body element
        document.body.classList.toggle('theme-dark');

        // Save the theme preference in a cookie
        document.cookie = "mybg=" + currentTheme + "; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/";
    }

    // Set initial theme based on the cookie
    window.onload = function () {
        var currentTheme = "@currentTheme";
        if (currentTheme === "dark") {
            document.body.classList.add('theme-dark');
        }
    };
</script>
<style>
    .theme-dark {
        background-color: #1f1f1f; /* Dark background color */
        color: #ffffff; /* Light text color on dark background */
        /* Additional styles for dark theme elements */
    }
</style>

Layout
<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">IdentityProj8</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
            <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <partial name="_Partial" />
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>


thank you for the code, it is very helpful. Why does it return to default (theme-light) on page refresh?

Hi @Fillo, It will only return to default theme if the cookie expired or deleted. From my project it will not cause I set the cookie in js with expired time expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT.  Maybe you need check why your set cookie expired/deleted.

The strange thing is that i did not change nor delete anything, it is just the code you posted, i did just copy/paste.

There was some problem with my app. I created a new one and it works flawlessly. Thank you.
